# Data scraping from the web using dart

Tags: dart

I am making a web application, in which i need to scrape the web to get some data. I can't see a way to do this without using the dart:io.HttpConnection which is not imporatble for web apps. What should i do, Can i make a server application and then use it with a client version, or something else?

Comment: Have you solve this issue ?

Comment: see it, there is a lot of options : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to build this server side since the [browser security model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) does not allow you to connect to other origins than the one that served your application (unless of cause you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) to do the scraping but I doubt that). So you need to create a service on your server that uses [HttpClient](http://api.dartlang.org/io/HttpClient.html) to do the scraping for you and then call this service from your client using [XMLHttpRequest](http://api.dartlang.org/html/XMLHttpRequest.html)

Comment: Do you have any examples on how would one do that ?